# iPhone audio bluetooth

Tags: iphone, audio

I have a 2012 Prius C. The Bluetooth for the phone works fine but the audio to play music from my iPhone will not play over the car radio.  Why does one work and not the other?  How do I fix it?  Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the relevant passage from the 2012 Prius C's user manual:

Before using the Bluetooth® audio/phone, it is necessary to register a Bluetooth® device in the system. Follow the procedure below to reg-
ister (pair) a device:
Press the tune knob and select “Bluetooth” using the tune knob.
Press the tune knob and select “Pairing” using the tune knob.
A passkey will be displayed.
Input the passkey into the device.
Select “Yes” to register the device. Depending on the type of device, it may register automatically.
If a Bluetooth® device has both music player and cellular phone func-
tions, both functions will be registered at the same time. When delet-
ing the device, both functions will be deleted at the same time.
If the off-hook switch is pressed and the “PHONE” mode is entered
when no phones have been registered, the registration screen will be
automatically displayed.

Basically, the music should just work. Try re-setting it up again and report back by commenting under this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot give you specific steps as I don't own that car, but in many vehicles, there are different settings for phone-use bluetooth and media-streaming bluetooth. In my car, you must specify which option the device should be used for. I know this answer doesn't solve your problem off the bat, but go into your car's manual and check it out. Or check in different menus, like preferences, phone, or media. Good luck.